# Convert Mathematical Formula into Python Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, syntax, equation

I have these mathematical equations that I must convert into python code. I've been trying for hours but couldn't get the results right.
Here are the Mathematical equations and their code that I have written so far.

[image: Equations]

```
class Mortgage:
    def __init__(self,L,Y,p,k):
        self.L = L
        self.Y = Y
        self.p = p
        self.k = k
        self.equation1()
    def equation1(self):
        self.p = self.L * ((1 + (self.p/365)) ** (365 * self.Y))
        p2 =(((1 + (self.p/365)) ** (self.k)) - 1) / (((1 + (self.p/365)) ** (365 * self.Y)) -1)
        print(p2)
        self.p *= p2
    def equation2(self,n):
        self.b = self.L * ((1 + (self.p/365)) ** (365 * n))
        b1 = ((1 + self.p/365) ** (365 * n)) -1
        b2 = ((1 + self.p/365) ** (self.k)) -1
        b3 = b1/b2
        p = self.p * b3
        self.b -= p
    def show_outputs(self):
        n = 0
        b = self.equation2(n)
        x = []
        y = []
        y.append(b)
        x.append(0)
        while b > 0:
            n += 1
            b = self.equation2(n)
            x.append(n)
            y.append(b)
        print(x)
        print(y)

m = Mortgage(200000, 10, 4.8, 14)
m.show_outputs()
```

Now, When I make the object of above class and execute the program, I get the following error:

```
**OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')**
```

A little help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please fix the indentation, and provide the code that actually calls the method.

Comment: Note in equation1 you override the vale of self.p with the statement ```self.p = self.L * ((1 + (self.p/365)) ** (365 * self.Y))``` and again with the statement ```self.p *= p2```

Comment: @trincot I've updated the code. Could you please review again? Thanks!

Comment: Note that in equation2, the result of the equation should decrease as the n increases. But the equation is not doing that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would easier to make an intermediate variable to take the daily interest term, so you don't get confused with all the brackets. But the most important problem is that you are overwriting the interest rate (self.p) with the repayment amount, so this needs to be a distinct field in the class:

```py
class Mortgage:
    def __init__(self,L,Y,p,k):
        self.L = L
        self.Y = Y
        self.p = p
        self.k = k
        self.rpy = L # temporary value
        self.equation1()
    def equation1(self):
        dy_int = 1 + (self.p/365)
        self.rpy = self.L * dy_int ** (365 * self.Y)
        p2 = (dy_int ** self.k  - 1) / (dy_int ** (365 * self.Y) -1)
        self.rpy *= p2
```

Also by my reading of the values, `p` is a proportion, not a percentage, so 5% interest would have `p == 0.05`

By contrast, Bn is not really intrinsic to the class, so it should return a value rather than updating the state:

```py
    def equation2(self,n):
        dy_int = 1 + (self.p/365)
        bn = self.L * dy_int ** (365 * n)
        b1 = dy_int ** (365 * n) - 1
        b2 = dy_int ** self.k - 1
        b3 = b1/b2
        bn -= self.rpy * b3
        return bn
    def show_outputs(self):
        x = []
        for n in range(self.Y+1):
            b = self.equation2(n)
            x.append((n,b))
        print(x)
```

Comment: I've edited the code with the calling method too. Note that, the value of b in equation 2 should decrease as the value of "n" increases. But the code is not doing that..

Comment: @SyedZubair note that 4.8 as p value is 480% interest rate.

Comment: @SyedZubair your `show_outputs` tries to get a value back from the `equation2` method but that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Figured it out with your help. Just had to divide the interest rate by 100 and it worked like a charm.